# How can I check/compare my JavaScript code speed/performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there any way to check/compare JavaScript codes' performances on my pc/browser?

Like,

Method 1:

```
var x = 3;
if (x === 1) {
  console.log(1);
} else {
  console.log(2);
}
```

Method 2:

```
var x = 3;
switch (a) {
  case 1: 
    console.log(1);
    break; 
  default: 
    console.log(2);
  }
```

Here, 'Method 1' and 'Method 2' both does the same thing, and if I search on the internet there might be several benchmarks to prove which method is faster/efficient.

But I want to check it myself (offline methods, i mean on my pc would be better for me).

Thanks :)

Comment: Check http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that, but is there any way I can do that on my browser/pc? Like Chrome Dev Tools has a lots of features, Does it supports those performance checking too?

Comment: @MARUF: Chrome's dev tools have performance stuff in them, yes, but as a one-off you're not going to see enough difference to measure. You'd have to use a loop, which opens you up to all kinds of problems because what you're testing is synthetic rather than real.

Comment: @MARUF: FYI, unlike C or Java, `switch` and `if`/`else if`/`else` are effectively the same thing in JavaScript. I'd expect your two code examples above, if they were identified as performance-critical, to end up being compiled to the same machine code by Chrome's V8 engine, for instance.

Comment: @MARUF: Instead of micro-optimizing ahead of time, respond to performance issues in the real code if and when they occur.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I've got your point. The question came up to me when I was comparing .createElement() vs .html() . (https://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/103) In this link you can see, there is a lot difference regarding execution time. i was hoping to check those milliseconds myself.

Comment: http://benchmarkjs.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check the performance by using "console.time"

Try this,

For Method 1 :

```
console.time('Method #1');

var x = 3;
if (x === 1) {
  console.log(1);
} else {
  console.log(2);
}

console.timeEnd('Method #1');
```

For Method 2:

```
console.time('Method #2');

var x = 3;
switch (a) {
 case 1: 
   console.log(1);
 break; 
default: 
   console.log(2);
}

console.timeEnd('Method #2');
```

Comment: I doubt that that will yield any reasonable timings. Better run each method a few 100K times

Comment: @robertklep it definitely will not, since modern engines (de)optimise as code warms up.

Comment: @zerkms yeah, even those "100K" iterations will probably not yield any _really_ useful results with this code.

Comment: @robertklep there is a good chance both will be optimised to something very similar if not identical :-)